# There doesn't seem to be a reputation level listed for the "edit tag wikis" priveledge

Tags: discussion, reputation, tag-wiki

I just noticed that even though a lot of rep levels necessary for privs are quite low since this is a beta site, the "edit tag wikis" priv isn't listed at all.

Not only that but we seem to be able to make a couple of suggested edits and then the system tells us "you need 2000 rep to be able to edit tag wikis".

What gives? It seems easier to edit tag wikis with low rep on an established SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've played around with some more tags, I think the "you must have at least 2000 reputation" message shows up if you normally would have to have your edit reviewed by someone else **and** there is already an edit for that tag pending in the queue.  If there is no edit pending, you get the normal page for entering a suggested edit and your edit is placed in the queue.

I suspect this because yesterday there were some tags where I couldn't enter suggested edits and others where I could (which wouldn't make sense if the queue was full).  Now that some more edits have been approved, I see the tags I couldn't enter anything on have gained a description from someone else and the ones where I could have suggested an edit are still blank.

So it's not the size of the queue so much as the tag you were trying to edit has a pending edit already.

As an example: Yesterday, I linked to [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) in my comment as an example of a tag I couldn't edit, and at the same time the [colloquial](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colloquial) wiki page brought me to the normal page where you can propose an edit.  Today, the word-choice tag has gained a description while colloquial is still blank.

Edit:  Yep, [confirmation](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/the-edit-link-doesnt-appear-in-a-question/550#550) that a pending edit can prevents you from suggesting an edit (in addition to the queue being full).

Comment: Thanks for the diagnosis. I think this should be reported as a bug. Just a user interface bug of course since it's only a bit confusing. It's not a "technical bug". A message telling you you can't edit due to pending edits but may still be able to edit other tag wikis would do.